# c3.js - how to show hand cursor on bar chart hover

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, c3.js

In pie charts c3js by default shows a hand cursor (pointer) when pie slice is hovered. I would like to have the same behavior for each bars in a bar chart. How to achieve that?

I tried the below css but it shows the hand cursor even when you hover in between 2 bars.

```
.c3-event-rect {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

To clarify this is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7L53LLr0/5/)
I'd like to have pointer cursor only on bar items because only them are clickable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After way too much time spent, I finally figured out *a* solution. [Here is a **jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7L53LLr0/16/), which explains the two lines of code in some detail (in comments).

If you don't understand the details, don't worry about it or just ask me to elaborate. :)

*tl;dr*:

1. `data: { 
       selection: {
           enabled: true 
       },
    [...]`
2. `.c3-bar {
      cursor: pointer;
   }`

Comment: Nice! You might want to add an explanation when you get the time. Cheers!

Comment: Like I said, its details are explained in the comments

Comment: Works great. Exactly as I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following CSS

```
.c3-bar {
    pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

Note that you need the `!important` to override the inline `pointer-events: none` that C3 adds to the bars.

Comment: Thanks. It does the trick with pointer cursor but on the other hand this solution blocks onclick event on the bar. As you can check at http://jsfiddle.net/7L53LLr0/6/

Comment: @MarkZ , at least on my browser, it doesn't block onclick events. Can you describe what event exactly isn't happening that you want to have happen (onclick)?

Comment: As you can see on original version (http://jsfiddle.net/7L53LLr0/7/) click on a bar chart causes alert popup with value message. This version is not desired because cursor is normal when you hover a bar. Version with your css fix (http://jsfiddle.net/7L53LLr0/6/) makes cursor as a desired hand but after click on a bar nothing is happening. I tested it on Chrome, IE 11 and Firefox. On all of them the behavior is the same.